# How to properly use JPA Inner Self Join query?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, inner-join, nativequery

Im new to JPA Query and my JPA Self Inner Join on the same table is not working but the SQL query works

This is the JPA query Im using

```
SELECT T.codeAuth FROM CodeCm T INNER JOIN Codecm K ON T.langCode = K.langCode where K.code= code1 and K.codeGroup = 
code_group1 and T.code= code1 and T.codeGroup= code_group1 ;
```

My columns

```
  @Basic()
  @Column(name="CODE", nullable=false, length=20)
  private String code;

  @Basic()
  @Column(name="CODE_GROUP", length=20)
  private String codeGroup;

  @Basic()
  @Column(name="LANG_CODE", length=2)
  private String langCode;
```

The exception Im getting is

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException:  Encountered "INNER JOIN Codecm K" at character 33, but expected: [".", "FETCH", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", <IDENTIFIER>].
```